# rails form_tag and hidden field of autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have implemented twitter's typeahead. And in one of my forms I would like to a hidden_field to be populated by the id of the data when the suggestion is selected or auto-completed. But the value of the hidden field is not being assigned the id.

My form tag looks like:

```
<%= form_tag students_path, :method => :get do %>
 <div class="input-group">
   <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, class: "load_students, form-control", placeholder: (params[:search] || t("search...")) %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :student_id, class: 'student_id' %>

   <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
     </button>
   </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

# and my js code is below

```
 #######There is more js code here
}).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted',
  function(data){
  $('.student_id').val(data.id);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting the data in the function and it has id?

Comment: Try using console.log to show you what is returned in data - `console.log(data);`. Add this in the typeahead function and check your browser console.

Comment: Yes I tried it with alert and data.id has the correct id

Comment: inspect and see HTML equivalent of this  `<%= hidden_field_tag :student_id, class: 'student_id' %>` because hidden_field_tag syntax is `hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`

Comment: <input name="student_id" id="student_id" value="" class="student_id" type="hidden">

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, just mostly use  " ", like `$(".student_id").val(data.id);`